# (CRUD) How to know which database records to target from html rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, crud

Been googling and trying all kinds of things but still can't figure it out.

Suppose i have a html form which has a table with lines (and input fields) in it. The lines have been populated by database (mysql) data. It is a journal with journal lines.

When the user changes one or more values of certain table rows and afterwards presses the save button, i want  to only change the affected rows in the database.

Have been using delete * from table for a while now and then re-inserting all table rows. Crude, but for now it works. (but the autoincrement ID goes up fast and dependant rows in other tables sometimes raise problems)

The whole problem is that i dislike the idea of sending the record's ID to the client and sending it back when the save button has been pressed. Amongst other thoughts, i don't think an internal SQL ID belongs in the client.

There's got to be another way and someone else must've done this before, right?

Sure you can do things like keeping track of changes in the client, using UUIDs (insert them in the table and send that as the temp ID in the client) or keep a line number both in the client and in the table. But it takes a lot of work and feels either slow(er) or cumbersome.

And sure it gets even worse when you let the user add or delete rows to the html table and process changes those in the database

Does anyone have any pointers for me? I would be most grateful.

Comment: In database, an "Update" operation is different from "Delete " + "Reinsert". (otherwise there is no need to have syntax like update [tablename] set xxxx=xxxxx where [key]=xxxxxxx )

Comment: *"i don't think an internal SQL ID belongs in the client."* - Why not? IDs like this are literally everywhere in client side code/mark up. This is definitely the best way to do it. Have a look at the URL of this question, the number you see, that's the ID of this question. Within the mark up of this comment, the database ID appears as a data attribute. Within the hyperlink to my profile, my particular internal UserID appears.

Comment: Gareth, yeah i know about the get string and sure, for some things its helpfull and can't do any harm in exposing it. But for more sensitive data its still a bit strange to me if you would send that to the client. Although: if every client of mine is working in their own environment and security forces them to only their own environment, no harm is done. Thanks for thinking with me

Comment: You've said that it is an auto_increment column though, so this cannot represent sensitive data? If you are using a natural primary key (i.e. real data not a meaningless integer) then I would follow Simon's advice and create a new meaningless unique identifier for each row, but this is only worthwhile if your existing unique identifier carries some kind of meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is add a `CLIENT_ID` column (or something like that) to my schema which would be a generated `uuid` and send that to the client along with the rest of the data and then send it back when the user hits `Save`. That way you don't have to expose the internal SQL ID, but you still have a way to identify certain entries in your DB. I'm not sure you can do this without sending some sort of ID to the client and then back to the server and even if you can, would it be worth the effort?